# Is there a way to mark component methods that used in html part of the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

angular-cli generated components contains an html and ts file. Ts file **might** contain methods which called in html.

I want to **mark/sign/distinguish the methods that are used in html**. I want this to make my implementation more robust and understandable.

For example, when I rename a method in ts, refactoring handles changing the function name on all ts files. **BUT** that function might be also used in html and I should manually find the usage and rename it.

Comment: If it isn't called by your template, make it private. You usually shouldn't have to export public functions in your component, put those inside a *_util.ts.

Comment: use webstorm. it refactors all the method occurrences correctly, including templates.

Comment: @Fyodor I'm using vscode. I might try webstorm one day ;)

Comment: No, it can't. Assuming we're still talking angular here.

Comment: it is very interesting that if a component method is **private** and it is being used inside the HTML template of the component when I run `ng serve` it works fine. When I run `ng build` and serve that, it still runs fine. **BUT**, when I run `ng build --prod` it gives an error. Very strange!